# conditional format to flag the duplicate using wildcard

Tags: google-sheets

Let say i want to check column D to see if there's duplicates.

I normally use this formula (in conditional formatting) to color the cell if there's multiple same value ( exact same value) :

```
=countif($D$1:$D,$D1)>1
```

But now i want to check if there's the similarity in first 3 letters, For example i want this to be warned as duplicates error.

```
How
Howy
Hows
```

I tried to use wildcards , it works on cell but not working when i use in conditional formatting.

```
=countif($D$1:$D ; left($D1,3) & "*")>1
```

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule you quote should work just fine. Check that the **Apply to range** setting in the formatting rule is correct — it should start from row 1.

To skip blank cells, use this:

`=len($D1) * (countif($D$1:$D , left($D1,3) & "*") > 1)`